# How this javascript code can detect HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I use this js function for converting my English numbers to Persian in my web pages but how can i develop below code to detect html tag . for example if i have tag DIV with ID "en" this function don't convert data inside this tag ...

```
<br>
<* or div id=en><* or div><br>
```

My code:

```
function TraceNodes(e) {
    if (e.nodeType == 3) e.nodeValue = e.nodeValue.toPersianDigit();
    else
        for (var t = 0; t < e.childNodes.length; t++) TraceNodes(e.childNodes[t])
}
String.prototype.toPersianDigit = function(e) {
    return this.replace(/\d+/g, function(t) {
        var n = [],
            r = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            n.push(t.charCodeAt(i))
        }
        for (var s = 0; s < n.length; s++) {
            r.push(String.fromCharCode(n[s] + (!!e && e == true ? 1584 : 1728)))
        }
        return r.join("")
    })
};
TraceNodes(document);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use `lang` attribute to indicate language of content.

So your code should look like:

```
function getParentLang(node) {
    var defaultLang = 'fa';
    var currLang = null;
    while(currLang === null && node.parentNode) {
        if (node.getAttribute && node.getAttribute('lang')) {
            currLang = node.getAttribute('lang');
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return currLang || defaultLang;
}

function TraceNodes(e) {
    if (e.nodeType == 3 && getParentLang(e) === 'fa' /* Persian */) {
        e.nodeValue = e.nodeValue.toPersianDigit();
    } else {
        for (var t = 0; t < e.childNodes.length; t++) {
            TraceNodes(e.childNodes[t]);
        }
    }
}
```

It traverses DOM tree to find first parent of node with specified `lang` attribute. If this attribute is equal to `'fa'` it calls your `toPersianDigit` method.